# Is The Wolverine based on any canonical source?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

Watching the trailer of the upcoming [The Wolverine](http://trailers.apple.com/trailers/fox/thewolverine/) I wondered, is it based on any canonical source?

So, is there any world / timeline / comic series where Wolverine either loses his regenerative abilities or got them suppressed?

Comment: Broadly, I believe the movie is based on the 4-issue limited series [Wolverine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_(comic_book)#Volume_1). I don't remember Wolverine's regenerative abilities being affected in that comic though, but it's some time since I've read it.

Comment: There may well be other canon stories where his healing powers were lost/suppressed, but I’m not familiar enough with Wolverine to know.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Hugh Jackman has said that the story-line is based off of the 4-issue limited series, as Paul D. Waite had. Realistically speaking, however, there will probably be some changes implemented. From what I have seen of the Trailer, there may be some elements from later parts of Canon, though this is purely speculation on my part.

I will, however, be seeing the Movie. Good Luck to all of us! :)